# How can I learn some juicy Incendiary Gossip?

Tags: fallen-london

I find myself thinking that maybe acquiring a key to rooms above a gambling den might be useful for my persuasive shadowy self, but I need 10 pieces of Incendiary Gossip before I can.

Apparently I can use Rumors items in my inventory, but I don't have any of those...so how can I go about getting some good juicy gossip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lacking lesser Rumour items, you can use the [Implacable Detective's Business Card](http://echobazaar.wikidot.com/implacable-detective-s-business-card) to exchange Whispered Secrets for Incendiary Gossip, if you have it.

More Opportunities to acquire Incendiary Gossip can be found by cultivating your connections with Bohemians, the Church and the Great Game.

Note: There is a [list of Storylets that result in acquiring Incendiary Gossip](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Incendiary_Gossip_Sources), if you wanted to see whether any Opportunities you currently have available would result in Incendiary Gossip (but that would be cheating now wouldn't it ;) ).